# Water Filtration System Issue

Tags: plumbing

Recently I purchased a home that is on well water. The water filter needs to be changed out about every three months, but because my house does not have a garage or basement, the water filter and water heater are both located in a small crawl space on the side of the house. I am in my late 60s, and find this arrangement to change the water filter untenable. Is there a way to re-plumb or change this set-up so I can have easier access to change the water filter when needed?

Comment: The placement is up to you.  Plumbing/pipes can always be moved/extended.  It will just depend on where you want the filter and/or heater.  Most people do not want them in the living spaces, but usually no reason not to have them there, except for looks.  A large closet can be built around them, if non are available.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with crip659’s comment. Plumbing can go just about anywhere; it’s mostly a matter of aesthetics and cost.

But before you hire a plumber, I suggest you look into the reason for using replaceable filters on your well water and consider other options such as self-maintaining filters that backflush contaminants down a drain or regenerate their active ingredients on a schedule. Almost every kind of replaceable filter can be had in a self-maintaining, backflushing or regenerating version. This could make your life easier.

You haven’t said what kind of filter you’re replacing every three months. If this is just a sediment filter and that’s all you really need, then re-plumbing to make filter changes easier is probably the way to go because sediment filter replacements are so inexpensive and automatic options are not.

If you had the well water tested before you bought the house, you can ask a new question in this stack that includes the results of the water test, then say what kind of filter you’re replacing every three months and ask about self-maintaining filters for this issue.

If you’re on a private well on your own property and you’ve never had the well water tested, it’s time. No other party is responsible for your drinking water but you. If you’re in the USA, search your state government’s website for their recommended testing of private well water. Some state universities also provide this info.